# glutStrokeCharacter to draw an int variable

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to draw an int to screen using the method glutStrokeCharacter using the following code

```
    int fuel = 400;
    std::string t = std::to_string(fuel);
    char *fueltxt;
    for (fueltxt = t; *fueltxt != '\0'; fueltxt++)
        {
            glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN , *fueltxt);
        }
```

I'm working on XCode and I'm getting the following error at the for loop, specifically at fuel txt = t

"Assigning to 'char*' from incompatible type 'std::string'(aka 'basic_string, allocator >')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the C++ way, using iterators:

```
int fuel = 400;
std::string t = std::to_string(fuel);

for (auto c = t.begin(); c != t.end(); ++c)
{
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *c);
}
```

If your compiler supports them, you could even use a range-based for loop:

```
int fuel = 400;

for (char c : std::to_string(fuel))
{
  glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, c);
}
```